# Error when firing trigger in SSIS package (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package.
In this package i have a data flow in which i am Inserting into a DB(destination) a CSV(source).

The package works perfectly.
The problem occurs when i am trying at the same time to fire the Triggers. To do that i am editing the Properties of the destination component. Specifically at properties i am adding the `,FIRE_TRIGGERS` bellow:

```
FastLoadOptions | TABLOCK,CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,FIRE_TRIGGERS
```

Now when i run the package i get the following error:

`[OLE DB Destination [139]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.".`

I followed this article [Unable to access sql server configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462050/unable-to-access-sql-server-configuration-manager) and i simply executed the following command from Admin-CMD (i have the SQL Server 2016)

`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared"
Then Run :
mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof`

But still nothing.

Thanks for any help!

My system: Windows10, SQL Server 2016, Visual Studio 2015

Edit:The trigger code is the following:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AccidentsTrigger
GO
USE SSIS_db;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER AccidentsTrigger
ON [Accidents]
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (SELECT [second_road_class] FROM INSERTED) LIKE '-1'
    BEGIN;
        UPDATE a
        SET [second_road_class] = '6'
        FROM [Accidents] AS a
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON a.accident_index = i.accident_index AND i.[second_road_class] = '-1';
    END;
END;
GO
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.  You would need to post your trigger code if you still need help finding the error.

Comment: I didn't post the trigger code because when i am executing a simple Insert through SSMS everything is working fine!
Update: I editing the original post and included the trigger code.
Edit: There is indeed something wrong with the trigger. I was testing it with a single row, but for multiple rows it's malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there were two bugs. The Trigger's result in multiple rows and the fact tha SQL Server Agent was on Manual start by default (it needs to be on Automatic). One can access SQL Server Agent service by SQL Server Configuration Manager.